# PHP - Simplifying Redundant HTML Formatting w/ PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, oop

I find myself frequently repeating HTML code to format items such as lists, tables, and other areas that have the save format repeated (ie: staff photos). I know there has to be some way to simplify HTML output for sections that use repeated formatting, but I'm not sure if an Array is applicable or if there's a better way that I haven't quite discovered.

As an example, I recently developed a store listing directory for the Macon Mall. This is one section of code:

```
<ul>
   <li>Belk<br /><span class="both">Upper &amp; Lower Level</span><br />(478) 477-2355</li>
   <li>JCPenney<br /><span class="both">Upper &amp; Lower Level</span><br />(478) 477-8400</li>
   <li>Macy's<br /><span class="both">Upper &amp; Lower Level</span><br />(478) 471-3847</li>
   <li>Sears<br /><span class="both">Upper &amp; Lower Level</span><br />(478) 471-5555</li>
</ul>
```

How could I simplify the process of inputting this by utilizing the power of PHP?

I hope I've made myself clear. Feel free to ask questions if not. Thanks for the help, all!

Comment: write a function, pass the data as variable(s), add the html to the vars in the function. Or  use one of the many template engines for php.

Comment: are your entries database generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$stores = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Belk',
        'level' => 'Upper & Lower Level',
        'number' => '(478) 477-2355'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'JCPenney',
        'level' => 'Upper & Lower Level',
        'number' => '(478) 477-8400'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Macy\'s',
        'level' => 'Upper & Lower Level',
        'number' => '(478) 471-3847'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Sears',
        'level' => 'Upper & Lower Level',
        'number' => '(478) 471-5555'
    )
);
?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach( $stores as $store): ?>
        <li><?= $store['name']?><br /><span class="both"><?= htmlspecialchars( $store['level']) ?></span><br /><?= $store['number']?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: yep, this is possible, but how is it any better than straight html?

Comment: You can dynamically change the list without needing to modify the HTML. And yes, `<?= ?>` is shorthand syntax for `<?php echo ?>` (I believe it requires short tags to be enabled).

Comment: It is messier than straight HTML when results are always the same.. But it could help a lot if the results where dynamically generated in some way (user input, database query etc.)

Comment: true, but why? You still have input the data.

Comment: @anpel yep, that's what I was getting at.

Comment: How else would the script get the data if you don't input it _somewhere_? PHP magic and witchcraft?

Comment: @AnPel - Yes, <?= is short for echo, but I believe it's been deprecated.

Comment: @WesDollar - I do not think it is deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: @Paul - No Paul, you're missing the point. The question was for "some way to simplify HTML output for sections that use repeated formatting", using the sample HTML provided. While the example is trivial, the solution is easily extendable and applicable to all cases of repeated formatting. AND, if the HTML needed to change for a repeated section, it has to be done *once* in the loop, and not X amount of times across multiple lines of HTML. This is code maintainability 101.

Comment: a simple include file would have been just fine. I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm just pointing out the fact that this is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing everything you can within your limitations. A CMS might ge something to explore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to venture into something new, I suggest experimenting with the closure capability of PHP. You will see from the example how easily you can completely remove HTML from your code. I intend to develop a library around this (forms, etc), but the core concept is very simple. Start with this function (don't worry how it works for now):

```
function h($code , $id="", $class=""){
    if ($id !== "") $id = " id = \"$id\"" ;
    $class =  ($class !== "")? " class =\"$class\"":"";
    $open = "<$code$id$class>";  
    $cls = trim(substr($code,0,strpos($code.' ',' ')));
    $close = "</$cls>"; 
    return function ($inner = "") use ($open, $close){
        return "\n$open\n$inner\n$close\n";};

}
```

Now this code:

```
//Create two simple tags (Why not an entire page layout!)
$tags = array('ul','li');
foreach ($tags as $element)
   $$element = h( $element);

//Create the span tag with its class...
$span=h("span", "", "both");

//Creating an optional div with an id
$div = h("div", "test");

//Constant linebreak
$br = "<br />";

//more optional tags
$bold = h('strong');
$italic =  h('i');
```

//  Now here is your "closed" HTML!

```
echo $ul(
   $li("belk".$br.$span("Upper &amp; Lower Level").$br."(478) 477-2355").
   $li("JCPenney".$br.$span("Upper &amp; Lower Level").$br."(478) 477-2355").
   $li("Macys".$br.$span("Upper &amp; Lower Level").$br."(478) 477-2355").
   $li("Sears".$br.$span("Upper &amp; Lower Level").$br."(478) 477-2355")
);
```

First of all, you notice there are no closing tags! That is because of the closure function acts like a bun and closes your burger with the two halves! Notice how the closure function

> h()

returns a function! The closure takes a snapshot of the environment (in this case the opening and closing tags with their attributes) and when its called again it remembers to put them in the right place.

Who said we can stop there! You can nest all the HTML you want and everything comes out correctly! With this technique you never have to dirty your views with raw HTML. Nothing is stopping you from creating functions that receive arrays and map HTML directly around each element.